# Export functions from static library to shared

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, static-libraries

In Android NDK I try to build shared library from small "modules" - static libraries. For example:

***Android.mk:***

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := module1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := module1.c

include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := module2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := module2.c

include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := main-module

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := module1 \ module2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But functions from module1 and module2 are not visible when I try to call them from shared libary (main-module).

Functions from module1.c and module2.c are exportable because I can call them direct if build such library for example:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := module1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := module1.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How can I mark functions from static libraries visible in shared library (as described in first example). May be any compiler/linker flags required?

Answer (score 1):

Use BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY instead of PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY.

The former is how you define a 'static library' module that will contain the object files obtained by compiling the sources in LOCAL_SRC_FILES.

The latter isn't recognized by ndk-build and will be silently ignored.

Just for clarification, there also exists PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY (note the "T"), which is used when you have a binary library file (e.g. libmodule1.a) instead.

See $NDK/docs/ANDROID-MK.html for mode details.

Comment: Thanks for a hint "T" you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY also doesn't works. I think the reason is that the main-module doesn't use any source files and if I include at least one source file that uses functions from one of the modules these modules will be included to the main-module. For example:

***Android.mk:***

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := module1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := module1.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := module2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := module2.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := main-module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mainmodule.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := module1 \ module2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In example mainmodule.c uses some functions from module1 and module2.

But how to include static modules to the main-module without mainmodule.c?